# How to show certain values in a dependent field to only certain profiles?

Tags: salesforce, force.com

**SETUP and GOAL**

I have a controlling field TYPE with a dependant field SUBTYPE. I want to add two options in the dependent field that is only visable to 1 record type (or a defined set of profiles).

**Confusion**

My boss, said we can do this- since we're making additions to only 1 controlling field column. I thought this was not possible because if you make these additions availible to a controlling field option (via the field dependency matrix), then anyone who can see that controlling field   (via record type) should see the options. (the intersection thing from https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_dependent_field_considerations.htm )

**Questions:**

I don't get why this is possible (i'm thinking in terms of set theories here) and moreover how to do it.

Thanks,

-Das Noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record Type rules over dependancies...

Record Type 1 has
Type
  TA
  TB

SubType
   STA1
   STA2
   STB1
   STB2

Record Type 2 has
Type
  TA
  TB

SubType
   STA1
   STB1

So for nothing to do with dependancies!
So these above are what people can see for each record type...now let's add dependancies...

We'll make STA1/STA2 dependent on TA
We'll make STB1/STB2 dependent on TB

Fine!
Record Type 2 can still NOT see STB2 hey select TB! (record type restriction)
Record Type 2 can ONLY see STB2 IF they select TB! (dependancy)

So just add your 2 values to SUBTYPE.
Make those 2 values visible to the proper Record Type.
Edit your dependancies (and don't think about Record Types, just make the dependancie).
Now log in as User 1 and test.
Now log in as User 2 and test.

You should be good to go!

When it doubt, test it out!

Answer (score 1):

An option has to be enabled in the record tpe to be visible (for controlling) and additionally to be enabled in the matrix (for controlled) so I dont see a problem here. Just add options to dependent field, attach them to their controlling values and only enable them for the desired record type.

In terms of set theory, the set of visible dependent options is an intersection of those enabled for record type and tohose present in the matix for the current controlling option. When either of those changes, the set is recalculated (in theory ;))

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't this affect ALL record types that have that controlling field selected in their profiles? - so if I have profile A and B, both that need access to that controlling field- Why are the dependent fields only exposed to A and not B?

Comment: Can someone help me with this clarification? I have to make these changes soon and put them into QA..